# dynamic page turn function - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to write a dynamic function for an element with several pages. At time just one page is visible and with a click on the forward or backward button the next or previous page is shown.

I have several of these elements with different amount of pages.

```
function pageTurn(forwardID, backwardID, pageClass, counter, numbers) {
    var forward = document.getElementById(forwardID);
    var backward = document.getElementById(backwardID);
    var page = document.getElementsByClassName(pageClass);
    var count = document.getElementById(counter);
    var pageCount = 1;

    forward.addEventListener('click', function() {
        pageCount ++;
        count.innerHTML = pageCount + ' / ' + numbers;
        page[pageCount - 2].classList.add('invisible')
        page[pageCount - 2].addEventListener("transitionend", OnTransitionEnd());

        buttonCheck();
    })

    backward.addEventListener('click', function() {
        pageCount --;
        count.innerHTML = pageCount + ' / ' + numbers;
        page[pageCount].classList.add('invisible')
        page[pageCount].addEventListener("transitionend", OnTransitionEnd());

        buttonCheck();
    })

    function buttonCheck() {
        //SHOW AND HIDE PAGETURN BUTTONS
        if(pageCount == 1) {
            backward.classList.add('invisible');
        } else if (pageCount > 1) {
            backward.classList.remove('invisible');
        } else if (pageCount == numbers) {
            forward.classList.add('invisible');
        } else if (pageCount < numbers) {
            forward.classList.remove('invisible');
        }
    }

    function OnTransitionEnd() {
        page[pageCount - 1].classList.remove('invisible');
    }
}
```

Same logic for the backwards button, just reversed.

I want the function to add value of 1 to the `pageCount` on a click on the forward button. To dynamicly add and remove the .invisible class from the `page` element i want to use the `pageCount` variable to choose the right page out of the class array. But it doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/1qt8p9of/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things to consider here: I think you'd be better of posting on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

However, here's a snippet where I slightly modified the code you provided to make it work. Don't hesitate to take a look!

```js
function initialize(forwardID, backwardID, pageClass) {
  const forward = document.getElementById(forwardID);
  const backward = document.getElementById(backwardID);
  const pages = document.getElementsByClassName(pageClass);
  let counter = 0;

  function buttonCheck() {
    if (counter <= 0) {
      backward.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else {
      backward.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

    if (counter >= pages.length - 1) {
      forward.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else {
      forward.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }

  forward.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pages[counter].classList.add('invisible');
    counter++;
    pages[counter].classList.remove('invisible');
    buttonCheck();
  });

  backward.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pages[counter].classList.add('invisible');
    counter--;
    pages[counter].classList.remove('invisible');
    buttonCheck();
  });
}

initialize('forwards', 'backwards', 'page');
initialize('forwards2', 'backwards2', 'page2');
```

```css
.pages .invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>First set of page</legend>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="backwards" disabled>&larr;</button>
    <button id="forwards">&rarr;</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pages">
    <div class="page">Page One</div>
    <div class="page invisible">Page Two</div>
    <div class="page invisible">Page Three</div>
    <div class="page invisible">Last Page</div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<hr />

<fieldset>
  <legend>Second set of pages</legend>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="backwards2" disabled>&larr;</button>
    <button id="forwards2">&rarr;</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pages">
    <div class="page2">Page One</div>
    <div class="page2 invisible">Page Two</div>
    <div class="page2 invisible">Page Three</div>
    <div class="page2 invisible">Page Four</div>
    <div class="page2 invisible">Last Page</div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Seems the 3rd "else if" was the reason why it didn't worked. Why is that? And what do you meant with "There's a lot going wrong here"? What else? I see you did it a bit different, but why?

Comment: Yeah, I was about to tell you about that! Nice job on your fiddle, it's pretty much the same code I wrote `:)`.

Comment: The 2nd `else if` checks that `pageCount > 1`. So, if `pageCount == numbers`, you also match `pageCount > 1`... and since you're using an `else` when checking if `pageCount == numbers`, you never get **there**, because you went into `pageCount > 1`!

Comment: I didn't mean to be mean when I said there was a lot you did wrong, but in the code you gave us at first, the `buttonCheck` function could not see the variables and I got scared you did not really understand javascript yet. I was wrong though! I hope you forgive me `;)`

Comment: ahh, okay. Didn't know that its a "loop" for every if - else if group. Thanks for the info, that gives me a huge impact of my javascript understanding!! THANK YOU! :) 
No no, i dont got it in the mean way, i ask to improve and know that my code isn't perfect. Every Suggestion is a plus for me :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!